# logout if inactive for 1 min

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my React native project I have signin page and drawer navigation which contains custom drawer with tab navigation. They are contains home, detail pages. if I logged in it navigates to home page or details page. What I want is if I inactive for 1 min then it should be autologout.

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Details from './src/pages/details';
import DrawerNavigator from './src/routes/drawerNavigator';
import SignIn from './src/pages/signin/signIn';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeByInput" component={DrawerNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```